# How to output a list onto a textbox in c#

Tags: c#

I'm using winforms.

I have a list `allWords` and I want to output it to a textbox `unique`

I tried

```
var thisFile = File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName);
var theseWords = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var line in thisFile)
{
   var split = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, 
   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   theseWords.Add(split.ToList());
}

thisTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, theseWords);
```

But my textbox just shows this
[image]

What do I need to change here?

From this text file (note there are multiple lines and words are seprated by spaces)

```
one two three four five
six seven eight nine ten
eleven twelve thirteen
```

my desired output would be

```
|--------------------------------|
|one, two, three, four, five, six|
|seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven |
|twelve, thirteen                |
|--------------------------------|
```

Comment: you'd better define how the words will be shown.

Comment: You need to edit your question if you want an answer.  There isn't enough information to help you.  For instance is this WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the lines into words using `.SelectMany` and that can then be filtered further for distinct words using `.Distinct()`

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName);
var words = lines
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Distinct();
thisTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words);
```

The above will put each distinct word on a new line.

If the desired output is to have each word separated by `,` then change last line to

```
thisTextBox.Text = string.Join(", ", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue your having is that you are adding lists (`var split = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }`) into you list `theseWords`.

What you may want to do is `join` the `split` list before adding it to you `theseWords` List. And change your list type from a nested List `List<List<string>>` to just a `List<string>`.

```
   theseWords.Add(string.Join(",", split));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
var thisFile = File.ReadAllLines(openFile.FileName);
var theseWords = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (var line in thisFile)
{
    var split = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    theseWords.Add(split.ToList());
}

thisTextBox.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, String.Join(" ", theseWords));
```

Your problem was that `List<List<string>>()` needs to be flattened twice. The line `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, theseWords)` only flattened once.